# How to create a list of base class inside the child class

Tags: python, oop

Here is what i couldn't figure it out.
Suppose I have a simple class like

```
class Card(object):
......
pass
```

and I want to create a class deck which inherits the Card class, like:

```
class Deck(Card):
......
self.cards = [....list of 52 Cards...]#this line is my question
```

so later I can access specific card from class deck , like:

```
#index is referring to the shuffled deck
d=deck()
print(d.index(5))
print(d.index(35))

output: 
('Jack','Diamond')
('5','Spade')
```

So in nutshell, my question is How to create a list of base class inside the child class?

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of subclassing. A deck is not a card.

Comment: Generally, you don't.  Inheritance represents an "is a" relationship.  So by subclassing `Card`, you're saying "Every Deck is also a Card".  Which doesn't make much sense.  Instead, `Deck`s should have cards, which would just be a list of `Card` objects

Comment: @PatrickHaugh meaning it is not possible or not good practice?

Comment: @DataScienceStep it just doesn't make sense.  For example, a `Card` object will likely have a value and a suit.  If `Deck` is a subclass of `Card`, then every `Deck` object will also have a value and suit, even though that doesn't make sense.  Instead, you probably want something like `self.cards = [Card(suit, value) for suit, value in itertools.product(suits, values)]`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thanks, I think I get it now, so this code can be used in Deck class which is not inheriting the Card class ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good use of inheritance. A deck shouldn’t be a subclass of card. Inheritance makes sense when the statement “ChildClass is a ParentClass” is correct. In your situation “deck is a card” doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @DataScienceStep you can have the Deck class, which maintains a list of Card, exactly like you did. There is no benefit in making Deck inherit from Card, because you don't want the Deck to behave like a Card, and you don't want other functions that accept a Card parameter to receive a Deck parameter instead. If you were looking for something like [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming), you don't actually need it in python because you can just assume that the Card objects will behave like a Card.